# Global Alias with apache on a system with multiple Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, alias, virtualhost

I'm confused with this: I'm running an apache web server with several Virtual Hosts and several Domains. What I like to achieve is a globally available Alias which is available in all Virtual Hosts.

I played around with something like this placed in the apache.conf:

```
Alias /my-test /srv/www/my-test
```

The alias works for the default/first host but not for the others. 
Is there any chance, to set this globally for all hosts so that I can access

```
domain1.com/my-test/doc.html
domain2.com/my-test/doc.html
...
```

with one Alias (or something else) defined in one place and not in each and every Virtual Host?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/744220/global-apache-alias-ignoring-virtual-hosts/744252#744252